# Spherical Fractals

Tags: fractals

Alright so for my work i am in the need of a Fractal with a spherical shape. Now, i have implimented a way to generate Fractals using a set of Equations. But so far i couldnt find a comprehensive source looking into Fractals which are to some extend or another spherical.

I do know that at N values tending to 1, something like the Julia set is a sphere. But it dosnt have any fractal features, its just a sphere.

Ideally i would want something like this: https://www.flickr.com/photos/syntopia/6854195470/in/photostream

Now the guy how made this did explain how, and he essentially just projected a 2D Fractal onto a 3D Surface and extruded it. Which wont work for my intended goal.

Something like this would be ideal:

[image]

But even here, to me, this dosnt look very 3D and more like a projection.

So to recap, i am looking for either a resource or set of equations which create Fractal geometry that has an overall spherical shape. If that is even a thing. Judging by how little there is on the subject i wouldnt be supprised if this is some sort of imposibility.

Thank you for reading and any help ! :D

Comment: Perhaps this discussion over on mathematica.statckexchange might help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/

Answer (score 1):

The most promising tool seems to be [Incendia](https://www.incendia.net), since it creates real fractals and not only projections.

[image]

Whether you can get at the algorithms is not immediately apparent, but possibly you get an idea of the principle behind them.

This [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08391) entitled "Self-similar space-filling sphere packings in three and four dimensions" by Stäger and Herrmann provides some algorithm that might go into the direction you want:

[image]

Another possibly relevant [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Sphere-inversion-fractals-Leys/a38339d8f6239c13599aab17d31cb915de66dcf3) is "Sphere inversion fractals" by Jos Leys:

[image]

Following literature on this topic lead me to the following papers too:

- "The Fractal Dimension of the Apollonian Sphere Packing" by Borkovec and Paris
- "A generalization of the spherical inversion" by Ramírez and Rubiano

Comment: The paper seems very much like what i need. But sadly i dont have that much time. However the software you linked might be even better. It has some user generated Fractals which always provide the equations. So.... that is useful :D Thank you very much !

Comment: Great, I am glad if this is helpful for you.